# OpenCV C++ drawContours Error

Tags: c++, opencv

```
Mat frame;
Mat frame2;
Mat output_frame;
Mat imgray;
Mat imgCanny;
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Point> approx;

Mat img = imread("abc.jpg");

cvtColor(img, imgray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Canny(imgray, imgCanny, 10, 100, 3, false);

findContours(imgCanny, contours, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
double eps = 0.1 * arcLength(contours[0], true);
approxPolyDP(contours[0], approx, 1, true);
drawContours(img, approx, 0, (0, 255, 0), 1);  // Here has Error..
```

I studied about OpenCV, but the `drawContours` method(?) is strange.

I mean other `drawContours` is done (`drawContours(img,contours,0,(0,255,0),1);`)

But `drawContours(img, approx, 0, (0, 255, 0), 1);` has error.

Why?

I confirm that the approx has data (4 dot points)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input of drawContours should be `vector<vector<Point> >` . 
here is minor modification of your code.

```
Mat frame;
Mat frame2;
Mat output_frame;
Mat imgray;
Mat imgCanny;
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Point> approx;

Mat img = imread("abc.jpg");
cvtColor(img, imgray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Canny(imgray, imgCanny, 10, 100, 3, false);

findContours(imgCanny, contours, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
double eps = 0.1 * arcLength(contours[0], true);
approxPolyDP(contours[0], approx, 1, true);
vector<vector<Point> > approx_t;
approx_t.push_back(approx);
drawContours(img, approx_t, 0, (0, 255, 0), 1);
```